# Programmatically select other sheet precedents or dependents in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> will sometimes directly switch to another sheet to show the precedents or dependents in that sheet.

I want that programmatically, because I want to get the precedents (or dependents) of a selection of cells.

`Range.Dependents` and `Range.Precedents` have [other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5541342/256431), but the solution there does not solve the extra-sheet issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a fair bit of Googling I found it was solved in [2003](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/printthread.php?t=126236).

But I used the code from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=297888).

The problem is that `Dependents` and `Precedents` are `Range` properties, which can't refer to multiple worksheets.

The solution uses `NavigateArrow` to locate the cross-sheet 'dents.

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub GetOffSheetDents(ByVal doPrecedents As Boolean)

Dim c As Range
Dim results As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim extra As Boolean

For Each c In Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
    Set r = oneCellDependents(c, doPrecedents)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        If r.Worksheet Is ActiveSheet Then
            ' skip it
        ElseIf sheet Is Nothing Then
            Set sheet = r.Worksheet
            Include results, r
        ElseIf Not sheet Is r.Worksheet Then
            If Not extra Then
                extra = True
                MsgBox "More than one external sheet in " & IIf(doPrecedents, "Precedents", "Dependents") & ". Only displaying first sheet."
            End If
        Else
            Include results, r
        End If
    End If
Next

If results Is Nothing Then
    Beep
Else
    results.Worksheet.Activate
    results.Select
End If
End Sub

Sub GetOffSheetDependents()

GetOffSheetDents False

End Sub

Sub GetOffSheetPrecedents()

GetOffSheetDents True

End Sub

Private Function Include(ByRef ToUnion As Range, ByVal Value As Range) As Range
If ToUnion Is Nothing Then
    Set ToUnion = Value
Else
    Set ToUnion = Application.Union(ToUnion, Value)
End If
Set Include = ToUnion
End Function

Private Function oneCellDependents(ByVal inRange As Range, Optional doPrecedents As Boolean) As Range

Dim inAddress As String, returnSelection As Range
Dim i As Long, pCount As Long, qCount As Long

If inRange.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Error.Raise 13

Rem remember selection
Set returnSelection = Selection
inAddress = fullAddress(inRange)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With inRange
    .ShowPrecedents
    .ShowDependents
    .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, 1
    Do Until fullAddress(ActiveCell) = inAddress
        pCount = pCount + 1
        .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, pCount
        If ActiveSheet.Name <> returnSelection.Parent.Name Then

            Do
                qCount = qCount + 1
                .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, pCount, qCount
                Include oneCellDependents, Selection
                On Error Resume Next
                .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, pCount, qCount + 1
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then _
                    Exit Do
                On Error GoTo 0
            Loop
            On Error GoTo 0
            .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, pCount + 1
        Else
            Include oneCellDependents, Selection
            .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, pCount + 1
        End If
    Loop
    .Parent.ClearArrows
End With

Rem return selection to where it was
With returnSelection
    .Parent.Activate
    .Select
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function

Private Function fullAddress(inRange As Range) As String
With inRange
    fullAddress = .Parent.Name & "!" & .Address
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 7):

Mark did some good job, but this macro altogether did not go to 'dents in the same sheet and failed, when there were 'dents from multiple sheets, since the selection cannot be created from multiple sheet cells.

I personally needed all this functionality to replace the "Ctrl + [" and "Ctrl + ]" quick shortcut functionality for jumping to precedents and dependents. Unfortunately, these shortcuts are completely unusable on international keyboard, where these square brackets are buried under AltGr (right Alt) combination and Excel does not allow either Ctrl+AltGr+8 and Ctrl+AltGr+8 to give the same result and also there is no way to remap the default shortcuts.

So I improved the code of Mark slightly to fix these issues and removed the pop-up message from code, since I should know myself if I cannot select all 'dents, but I want the function to work smoothly without me having to click OK all the time. So the function just jumps to the sheet, which is linked first in the formula.

I hope this is useful for others as well.

The only thing what still bothers me is that while Application.ScreenUpdating = False Avoids jumping around the sheet and workbook, the arrows still keep blinking. Any way to avoid this?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub GetOffSheetDents(ByVal doPrecedents As Boolean)
'Main function, calling for separate function to find links to all cells to one of the input cells. Works for finding precedents for a whole selection (group of cells)
'doPrecedents is TRUE, if we are searching for precedents and FALSE, if looking for dependents
Dim InputCell As Range
Dim results As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each InputCell In Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
'Cycle to go over all initially selected cells. If only one cell selected, then happens only once.
    Set r = oneCellDependents(InputCell, doPrecedents)
    ' r is resulting cells from each iteration of input cell to the function.
    If Not r Is Nothing Then      'if there were precedents/dependents
        If sheet Is Nothing Then  'if this is the first time.
            Set sheet = r.Worksheet
            Include results, r
        ElseIf Not sheet Is r.Worksheet Then 'if new precedent/dependent is on another worksheet, don't add to selection (gets lost)
        Else
            Include results, r
        End If
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If results Is Nothing Then
    Beep
Else
    results.Worksheet.Activate
    results.Select
End If
End Sub

Sub GetOffSheetDependents()
'Function defines, if we are looking for Dependents (False) or Precedents (True)
GetOffSheetDents False

End Sub

Sub GetOffSheetPrecedents()
'Function defines, if we are looking for Dependents (False) or Precedents (True)
GetOffSheetDents True

End Sub

Private Function Include(ByRef ToUnion As Range, ByVal Value As Range) As Range
If ToUnion Is Nothing Then
    Set ToUnion = Value
    ElseIf Value.Worksheet Is ToUnion.Worksheet Then 'if new precedent/dependent is on the same worksheet, then add to selection
            'if new precedent/dependent is on another worksheet, don't add to selection (gets lost)
        Set ToUnion = Application.Union(ToUnion, Value)
End If
Set Include = ToUnion
End Function

Private Function oneCellDependents(ByVal inRange As Range, Optional doPrecedents As Boolean) As Range
'Function finds dependents for one of the selected cells. Happens only once, if initially only one cell selected.
Dim inAddress As String, returnSelection As Range
Dim i As Long, pCount As Long, qCount As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If inRange.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Error.Raise 13 'seems to check, that only one cell is handled, but does not seem to be necessary step.

'remember selection
Set returnSelection = Selection ' to keep initial selection for GetOffSheetDents function.
inAddress = fullAddress(inRange) ' takes address of starting cell what is analyzed.
pCount = 1

With inRange   'all functions apply to this initial cell.
    .ShowPrecedents
    .ShowDependents
    .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, 1 ' go to first precedent (if first argument is true)/dependent. But why required?
    Do Until fullAddress(ActiveCell) = inAddress
        .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, pCount 'go to first precedent, then second etc.
        If ActiveSheet.Name <> returnSelection.Parent.Name Then ' checks, if the precedent is NOT on the same sheet

            Do
                qCount = qCount + 1   'qCount follows external references, if arrow is external reference arrow.
                .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, pCount, qCount 'go to first exteranl precedent, then second etc.
                Include oneCellDependents, Selection
                On Error Resume Next
                .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, pCount, qCount + 1 'could remove this step and check for error before Include?
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do
                On Error GoTo 0  ' not sure if this is used, since if there is error, then already Exit Do in previous step.
            Loop
            On Error GoTo 0 'not sure, if necessary, since just asked in loop.
        Else  ' if precedent IS ON the same sheet.
            Include oneCellDependents, Selection
        End If
        pCount = pCount + 1
        .NavigateArrow doPrecedents, pCount
    Loop
    .Parent.ClearArrows
End With

'return selection to where it was
With returnSelection
    .Parent.Activate
    .Select
End With

End Function

Private Function fullAddress(inRange As Range) As String
'Function takes a full address with sheet name

With inRange
    fullAddress = .Parent.Name & "!" & .Address
End With
End Function
```

Comment: +1 as you've got a better general solution to a larger problem than I  had, but I've not switched the green tick because I _do_ want to know when I've not seen all 'dents.

Comment: In your added comments you ask about `On Error GoTo 0`. This turns off the `On Error Resume Next`, and you need to do it whether there's an error or not, thus in two locations.

Comment: And the `inRange.Cells.Count <> 1` check is just defensive programming.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I agree that it is a matter of preference, if we'd want to show the message or not. My purpose was simply different and probably it would be better to include the code and comment it out, so user can modify based on preference. For major auditing of a bigger model I have been very happy about a tool RefTreeAnalyser [link](http://www.jkp-ads.com/RefTreeAnalyser01.asp).

Comment: @kaidobor you have +5 for this answer! Please continue :)

Answer (score 0):

I found kaidobor's version of Mark Hurd's code exactly what I needed. I wrote a wrapper to document all the dependencies in the selected cells and insert them in a new sheet. My code just calls kaidobor's code and records the results.

My use case: I have a complex spreadsheet (written by someone else) that I need to clean up. I want to delete some sheets that appear unnecessary but want to know where I'll be breaking formulas before deleting the sheets. This will create an index showing all the cells that are referenced in other sheets.

```
Sub FindDependentsForThisSheet()
' Find all cells in the selection that have dependents on some other sheet
' Calls code by kaidobor
' January 9, 2017
Dim rCurrent As String, strNoDependents As String, strDependents As String, strCurrrentParent As String
Dim aDependents(1000, 4) As String ' Starting sheet, starting cell, referenced sheet, referenced cell
Dim intArrayRows As Long
strNoDependents = "No Dependents" & vbCrLf
strDependents = "Dependents" & vbCrLf
intArrayRows = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Step through each cell in the current sheet (for each…)
For Each cell In Selection.Cells
    ' improvement: step through just the cells that are selected in case I know some are not worth bothering with
    Range(cell.Address).Select
    rCurrent = ActiveCell.Address
    strCurrrentParent = ActiveCell.Parent.Name
    'Run GetOffSheetDependents() for each cell
    GetOffSheetDependents
    'GetOffSheetPrecedents
    'When GetOffSheetDependents() is done, if the ActiveCell.Address is not changed,
    'If (rCurrent = ActiveCell.Address And strCurrrentParent = ActiveCell.Parent.Name) Then ' We do care about links on the current sheet
    If (strCurrrentParent = ActiveCell.Parent.Name) Then ' Do not care about links on the current sheet
        'then nothing
        strNoDependents = strNoDependents & ActiveCell.Parent.Name + " - " + ActiveCell.Address & vbCrLf
    Else
        ' Stuff the array
        aDependents(intArrayRows, 0) = strCurrrentParent
        aDependents(intArrayRows, 1) = rCurrent
        aDependents(intArrayRows, 2) = ActiveCell.Parent.Name
        aDependents(intArrayRows, 3) = ActiveCell.Address
        intArrayRows = intArrayRows + 1
        strDependents = strDependents + strCurrrentParent + "!" + rCurrent + " referenced in " + ActiveCell.Parent.Name + "!" + ActiveCell.Address & vbCrLf
        '1 record ActiveCell.Address + parent.
        '2 return to home sheet and
        Sheets(strCurrrentParent).Select
        '3 record the address of the active cell
    End If
    If intArrayRows > 999 Then
        MsgBox "Too many cells, aborting"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
'Debug.Print strDependents
'Debug.Print strNoDependents

' Store results in a new sheet
If intArrayRows > 0 Then
    varReturn = NewSheetandPaste(aDependents)
    MsgBox ("Finished looking for dependencies. Created sheet with results. Found this many: " & intArrayRows)
Else
    MsgBox ("Finished looking for dependencies, found none.")
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
' ************************************************************************************************

Function NewSheetandPaste(aPasteThis As Variant) '(strSheetName As String)
' Create new sheet and past strDependents
Dim strName As String, strStartSheetName As String, n As Long
'strName = strSheetName + "Dependents"
strStartSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
strName = strStartSheetName + "Dependents"
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = strName
'Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "Sheet1Dependents"
Range("A1").Value = "Dependents from " + strStartSheetName
'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Dependents from Sheet1"
'Range("A2").Value = strPasteThis
Range("A2").Value = "Starting Sheet"
Range("B2").Value = "Starting Sheet Cell"
Range("C2").Value = "Dependent Sheet"
Range("D2").Value = "Dependent Sheet Cell"

Range("A3").Select
intLengthArray = UBound(aPasteThis) - LBound(aPasteThis) + 1
n = 0
'For n = 0 To intLengthArray
While aPasteThis(n, 0) <> ""
    ActiveCell.Value = aPasteThis(n, 0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = aPasteThis(n, 1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = aPasteThis(n, 2)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = aPasteThis(n, 3)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select
    n = n + 1
Wend

NewSheetandPaste = True
End Function
```