# Is there a way to identify all circular reference in Excel via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to identify all circular reference cells and record their addresses into an array. For now, I can use the Formula tab's Error Checking > Circular Reference and ActiveSheet.CircularReference to get the error. However, both of these methods only find one circular reference and left out other circular references in the worksheet. Is there a way to identify all of the circular references? Thank you

Comment: Do all your circular references refer to cells on the same sheet? Or, can some of them span onto other sheets?

Comment: @chrisneilsen On the same sheet

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Range.Precedents` property.  This returns a recursive set of cells that are referenced by a cell.  If that set includes the cell in question, then it's part of a circular reference.

Demo:

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFormula As Range
    Dim rPrecedents As Range
    Dim rCircular As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' change to suit your needs
     
    ' only consider cells with formulas
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rFormula = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not rFormula Is Nothing Then
        
        ' loop as Formula cells
        For Each rCell In rFormula
            ' Check if Formula references any cells
            Set rPrecedents = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rPrecedents = rCell.Precedents
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rPrecedents Is Nothing Then
                
                ' if Precenents includes rcell, then its circular
                Set rCircular = Nothing
                Set rCircular = Application.Intersect(rPrecedents, rCell)
                If Not rCircular Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print rCircular.Address
                    ' Add rCircular.Address to your array here
                    '...
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

<sub>Note that this will only work if *all* precedents are on the same sheet</sub>

Comment: thank you so much. if I want to check for links to other worksheets I just need to change to workbook scope?

Comment: No.  `Presedents` simply doesn't work with off-sheet references. But, you might be able to build something based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10897959/445425)