# Is there a way to implement VBA-Workbook_SheetChange across all sheets of a workbook for changing the cell color?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook that has multiple sheets.
There is a Master sheet where all the changes will be made.
The other sheets are Branches of the master that have linked cells to the master.

I know how to implement a worksheet_change to change the interior color of a cell when it is manually changed.

Is there a way to implement that same color change across all non-manually changed cells within the workbook?

Let's say cell A1 in sheet 1 has the word 'Hello'.

I want cell B2 in sheet 2 to have whatever cell A1 in sheet 1 has. Therefore cell B1 in sheet 2 would also have the word 'Hello'.

Now, let's say I change cell A1 in sheet 1 to 'Goodbye'

- I want cell A1 in sheet 1 to highlight in a light green color.
- I then want cell B2 in sheet 2 to say 'Goodbye' (which it will already do since it is linked to cell A1 in sheet 1) but more importantly, highlight cell b1 in that same light green color.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Target.Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
End Sub
```

This is what I use to change the color of a cell if it was changed on the master sheet. It does work, but just for that sheet.

I want to fill the background of all cells that were changed across the workbook.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897958/programmatically-select-other-sheet-precedents-or-dependents-in-excel)

Comment: The event is  `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`, but it's not useful in your case. Do you want this triggered only in e.g. `Sheet1` and then in all (or a list of) worksheets, the cell next to the same cell should be green and the cell in the next column and next row should be the value?.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I want to trigger the highlight when a change is made in the master. I also want the highlight to trigger in the cell that was changed in one of the branch sheets.

Comment: @Warcupine I have no idea how to understand that because I am very new to VBA. If it was Python or any other coding language I would probably be able to understand it more.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will apply to all sheets by adding a loop to it and itterating the sheets with their index nr.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        Call WorksheetLoop(Sh, Target)
    End Sub
    Private Sub WorksheetLoop(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim WS_Count As Long, i As Long
        WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        For i = 1 To WS_Count ' loop.all sheets but don't update the active one
            Worksheets(i).Range(Target.Address).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Consider the following example: [`Sheet1!A1`, `1`], [`Sheet2!B20`, `=Sheet1!A1+B1`],[`Sheet15!D40`, `=Sheet1!A1*25`]. If a change happens in `Sheet1!A1`, OP wants to color all three cells, but he doesn't know about the two other references or if there are any. This is manually done with `Formulas>Formula Auditing>Trace Dependents`. The link provided by Warcupine covers this in VBA, but it's rather complicated.