# Convert Formula's references to values in formula in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible using VBA to convert the formula =n2+m2 into its actual values on another sheet. For example cell m2 is 0, and n2 is 96,879 on sheet1. I'd like to have on sheet2 a formula be inserted in cell a1 for example, that is =0+96879. It is an audit trail of sorts. This would actually be performed on a large range, but that is the general idea. I've been looking for hours and come up with nothing.

Comment: Well it's probably *possible*, but unless you're working with relatively simple formula, it's gonna require a tremendous amount of string manipulation to parse the cell's `.Formula.Text` .  You'd need to parse out only the References from the formula...

Comment: There are a several options that go someway towards what you want [RefTreeAnalyser](http://www.jkp-ads.com/RefTreeAnalyser01.asp), [Aaron Bloods Explode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-HP010342448.aspx?CTT=1), and Rob Van Gelders [audxl](http://vangelder.orconhosting.net.nz/excel/audxl.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.  It's possible, but it's a pretty gnarly task.

Refer to this link, for some discussion about various methods:

[Does Excel have a built in method for parsing formulas? (ie: to obtain a list of included RANGE references)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320626/does-excel-have-a-built-in-method-for-parsing-formulas-ie-to-obtain-a-list-of)

Comment: gnarly indeed, I think my users will just need to go to sheet1 and check the references instead of trying to implement this.

Comment: You could use the `Trace Precedents` feature (if using a newer version of Excel) to assist. This will display the references and allow you to easily navigate to them.  http://imgur.com/Tr0ItIm

Comment: And on some further research... may be possible to able to adapt something like this: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=17028&p=86877#post86877 although I still think for anything more complicated than simple addition formulas, it would be really tricky to parse correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In sheet 2 A1 enter

```
 =Sheet1!n2&"+"&Sheet1!m2
```

If you want the = Sign to Then just do

```
="="&Sheet1!n2&"+"&Sheet1!m2
```

Comment: That works for simple formula, what about more complicated formula? OP will have to customize each formula on Sheet2 based on the structure of formula in A1, hence the reason I suspect OP asks for a VBA solution.

Comment: I was hoping for something this simple, but... my formula is simple n2+m2 but I was wanting the result visible, and once you click in the cell instead of seeing =sheet1!n2+sheet1!m2, you saw =(value)+value. This method would work if I just wanted the string visible.