# Parse excel cell validation list

Tags: c#, excel

I'm parsing an Excel file, with multiple columns and 2 rows:
first row is the column title, and the second row is for a user default value.
for example:

```
|   |  A   |       B        |  C   |
------------------------------------
| 1 |  ID  |      Name      | Room |
------------------------------------
| 2 |  0   |choose-from-list|  1   |
```

Since I want user to choose B2 value from list of options, I configured a data validation rule, and chose a range of values from another sheet.
So when I read the `Validation` property:

```
var cellDataValidation = cell.Validation;
```

The value of `Formula1` is:

```
"=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7"
```

The question is (finally): how can I use that expression, and get those cells from anther sheet (without regexp tricks, but using excel API).

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320626/does-excel-have-a-built-in-method-for-parsing-formulas-ie-to-obtain-a-list-of)?

Comment: well, he didn't find an answer, or indeed there is no API way.  
Moreover, I'm not quite sure how to find that range in another sheet

Comment: Try using Named range values that could do the trick :)