# VBA UDF fails to call Range.Precedents property

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a simple UDF, which is supposed to loop through each of the cells of a given_row, and pick up those cells which do not have any precedent ranges, and add up the values.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function TotalActualDeductions(given_row As Integer) As Integer

Total_Actual_Deduction = 0

For present_column = 4 To 153

    Set precedent_range = Nothing

    If Cells(2, present_column) = "TDS (Replace computed figure when actually deducted)" Then

        On Error Resume Next

        Set precedent_range = Cells(given_row, present_column).Precedents

        If precedent_range Is Nothing Then

            Total_Actual_Deduction = Total_Actual_Deduction + Cells(given_row, present_column)

        End If

    End If

Next

TotalActualDeductions = Total_Actual_Deduction

End Function
```

If I try to run it by modifying the top declaration, from:

```
Public Function TotalActualDeductions(given_row As Integer) As Integer
```

to:

```
Public Function TotalActualDeductions()
given_row = 4
```

then it runs successfully, and as expected. It picks up exactly those cells which match the criteria, and all is good.

However, when I try to run this as a proper UDF from the worksheet, it does not work. Apparently, excel treats those cells which have no precedents, as though they have precedents, when I call the function from the worksheet.

I don't know why this happens, or if the range.precedents property is supposed to behave like this.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Banish `On Error Resume Next` from your programming tool-bag. There are very, _very_ few times when it's the _only_ way to handle something and it's almost _never_ the best way. What you've done with that statement is swept any errors your code is generating under the rug and pretended nothing is wrong. With that line in there, you'll never figure out the problem.  Remove that and let the error throw to see what's going on.

Comment: I have put it intentionally. You see, if the cell does not indeed have any precedents, then "Set precedent_range = Cells(given_row, present_column).Precedents" throws an error, and it never enters the "If-Then" condition.

Comment: That's the problem. You set OERN, but you never _cancel_ it - that's one of the reasons why it's such a bad thing to use - that happens oto often. Somewhere after that an error is happening, but you've swept it under the rug. In this situation, you don't need it because your `Set Precedent_range` is followed by `if precedent_range is Nothing...` - you're already handling the error properly. Get rid of OERN and find out what the real error is.

Comment: @FreeMan No, you **do** need it here, but it should be reset with an `OEG0` immediately after.

Comment: @Rory, I stand corrected, you are also correct, `OEG0` should immediately follow. That's the main point.

Comment: So you mean I should use the err. Clear method? Or resume statement?

Comment: You should use `On Error Goto 0` immediately after the statement you expect may error. However, you can't use `Precedents` in a UDF, it just won't work properly - see Charles' page here: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I encountered this:

[When called from an Excel VBA UDF, Range.Precedents returns the range and not its precedents. Is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541342/when-called-from-an-excel-vba-udf-range-precedents-returns-the-range-and-not-it/5543993#5543993)

Apparently, "any call to .Precedents in a call stack that includes a UDF gets handled differntly".

So, what I did was use *Range.Formula Like "=[a-zA-Z]"* , because it satisfied my simple purpose. It is in no way an ideal alternative to the range.precedents property.

Foe a more detailed explanation, please visit that link.